# Working with unsaved associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have two models:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2

  def save
    self.attr = <sth. complex involving the associated model2 instances>
    super
  end
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1
end
```

The statement in the overwritten `save` method will issue a complex query (using `find` [or alternatively named scopes]) to calculate some aggregate value for some of the associated Model2 instances. The problem is that when a new Model1 instance along with some Model2 instances, this query will not return anything on the first `save` after the objects have been created and will return old data (the previous generation) for all consecutive `save` operations.

Is there a way to use `find` on the non-persisted in-memory state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course: it's called #select, or #inject, or any of the other -ect methods:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2

  before_save :update_aggregate_value

  private
  def update_aggregate_value
    # returns sum of unit_value for all active model2 instances
    self.attr = model2.select(&:active?).map(&:unit_value).sum
  end
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1
end
```

Remember in this case that the DB will *not* be hit, except if the model2 instances hadn't been loaded yet. Also, notice I used a before_save callback, instead of overriding #save. This is "safer" in that you can return false and prevent the save from proceeding.

Comment: a has_many attribute acts like an array you can do normal array like things to it even on unsaved objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for the before_save hint!